# Move derivative inside limit.

Tags: calculus

I know rules that allow me to interchange the limit and integral, like Lebesgue Dominated Convergence criteria, is it the very same criteria that we apply to derivatives? Can we use it to determine if we are allowed to do the folowing? $$ \frac d {dx} (\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n)= \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac d {dx} (f_n))$$

If anyone says that we are allowed to do it if $f_n$ converges uniformly, then why? And is there just a simple criteria we can check like Lebesgues?

Answer (score 3):

You have to have the uniform convergence of the derivatives.

Counterexample:
take
$$f_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac 1n + x^2}\to f(x) = |x|$$Check that this is uniform on every compact interval. But the limit of the derivatives taken in $0$ is 0, as the limit has no derivative at this point...